# Data not displayed by ng-repeat in Table

Tags: angularjs

Why the data is not displayed in the table i have created.

Here is the link to PLUNKER

[[1]: https://plnkr.co/edit/O3YFmJqyereOKhHXg8v1?p=preview][1]

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Login</th>
      <th>blog</th>
      <th>created_at</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="r in user1 ">
      <td>{{r.login}}</td>
      <td>{{r.blog }}</td>
      <td>{{r.created_at}}</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
```

But when i replace r by user1 in the above i get multiple rows with same content .Ideally i should get only 1 row

```
  <td>{{user1.updated_at}}</td>
      <td>{{user1.blog }}</td>
      <td>{{user1.created_at}}</td>
```

Can anyone explain the 2 issue that i have mentioned

Comment: user1 is a object not an array

Comment: so how can i display the data in the table?Or in other words how can i make my ng-repeat work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push the object to an array and iterate it

```
$scope.user1 = [] ;
 var OnUserComplete = function (data ){
 $scope.user1.push(data)
};
```

Comment: It's working $scope.user1 = [] ; convert object to array?

Comment: Yes, converting it to array so u can iterate in the table.